# trying to understand a code snip from l3prop

Tags: expl3, l3prop

Looking the implementation code of the l3prop, I got confused by the following part (in the definition of \prop_remove:Nn ) :

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__prop_split:NnTF #1#2
  { \exp_args:NNo \__prop_split_aux:NnTF #1 { \tl_to_str:n {#2} } }


\cs_new_protected:Npn \__prop_split_aux:NnTF #1#2#3#4
  {
    \cs_set:Npn \__prop_split_aux:w ##1
      \__prop_pair:wn #2 \s__prop ##2 ##3 \s__prop_mark ##4 ##5 \s__prop_stop
      { ##4 {#3} {#4} }
    \exp_after:wN \__prop_split_aux:w #1 \s__prop_mark \use_i:nn
      \__prop_pair:wn #2 \s__prop { } \s__prop_mark \use_ii:nn \s__prop_stop
  }


\cs_new:Npn \__prop_split_aux:w { }


\cs_new_protected:Npn \prop_remove:Nn #1#2
  {
    \__prop_split:NnTF #1 {#2}
      { \tl_set:Nn #1 { ##1 ##3 } }
      { }
  }
```

I got lost with the definition of \__prop_split:NnTF ... better said, my interpretation (from the code, not the function signature) it is a macro with just two parameters #1 #2
(even though, the signature suggests 4 parameters (the TF part)).

More so with the use/definition of \__prop_split_aux:NnTF
which is defined as a macro with 4 parameters, but when used (in \__prop_split:NnTF) only two parameters are given...

What is going on here ? (or what am I missing on those definitions?)

Thanks for any help.

Edit: not forgetting the weird (for me) definition of \__prop_split_aux:w
I mean, from the signature of \cs_set:Npn I would expect a csname (\__prop_split_aux:w) a parameter 'list' (##1) and then the 'code' itself (balanced), but instead I see (?!) just a token (\__prop_pair:wn)

Answer (score 5):

Every time TeX has to parse arguments it needs a little bit of time and if it picks up arguments unnecessarily it needs a little bit of unnecessary extra time. For that reason time critical applications avoid this if unneeded (that is a common technique and not specific to the L3 programming layer).

`\__prop_split:NnTF` picks up only 2 of its arguments directly and does something with them. As its final action it calls `\__prop_split_aux:NnTF` providing it with 2 arguments. As that command wants 4 arguments it gets the missing 2 (TF) from the input stream. This is the same as if `\__prop_split:NnTF` would have picked up 4 arguments and ended like this:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__prop_split:NnTF #1#2#3#4
  { \exp_args:NNo \__prop_split_aux:NnTF #1 { \tl_to_str:n {#2} } {#3} {#4} }
```

only slower because a possibly lengthy `#3` and `#4` is now read twice and passed around.
For commands that are called many thousand times in a document that adds up over time even on fast machines.

I agree with @egreg's comment below! The above is an explanation of what happens in the code you showed not a recommentation to use this in your own code. Doing these opimizations means less readable code for the sake of minimal speed improvements. That is only warranted in few places (and the parts of the kernel qualify but packages or user code seldom does). This is one of the reason while the kernel code is not necessarily a great place for learning how to use the L3 prog layer in higher-level code.

Comment: On the other hand, I'd recommend to avoid such optimizations for public functions and to define them with the parameter text matching the signature.

Comment: Indeed: you'll see in `siunitx` I don't do this as it makes the tracing results clearer and even for e.g. a table of lots of numbers, the hit is so small it's not worth it. But there are places we really do need every last gain we can, as Frank says.

Comment: Thanks.
(I was guessing (meanwhile) that it was some token trickery (TeX at it's finest, optimization)).
I was looking into it because I'm planning/trying to implement a 'structured array' (sort of a vector of records, or a vector of struct (C) )  the reason being that I have a few 'local classes' in which information is stored in macros like
csname: LABEL{counter}sublabel{subcounter}subsublabel{subsubcounter}
whose maintenance is always a pain.
AND I though about taking a look at how properties/keys where implemented (as a starting point).

Comment: @Alceu the idea of the L3 prog layer is that you don't have to (or should) define such highly optimized data structures yourself but simply use properties or list or ... by allocating some for your application and then use the provided accessor functions.

Comment: ...
yes, I agree,  between l3prop, l3keys, l3seq and l3tl there is almost no need for more general structures. 'My particular case', a set of students (last grad year) each with one or two 'final work', each work with an advisor and a set of reviewers.
Indeed, it's a very specific  case, and I was just 'trying around' to see if I could come up with a less error prone syntax (\\csname ) like
\setdata{student[i].work[j].reviewer[k].field}{value} (and/or, better yet, \setdata{student.work.reviewer.field}{value} ('using' the concept of iterators).

Comment: btw, I kind of 'give up' on the idea of a very 'low level implementation' (I mean, TeX), but I'm now working on a more 'middle level structured way' (meaning, using \seq_set_split at the dots and l3regex to 'verify' if brackets  are being used in a balanced way). it's not going to be as efficient (perhaps flexible) but shall do the work.